# Trying to align my icon font element at center is not working

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to do an effect when I hover over an image, I want to show a dark box closing and when the box is closed, I Want to show an icon font on the center of my image.

The effect already is working but my icon font is not staying centered.

I already tried `margin:0 auto, text-align:center`, but nothing is working.

I format my icon font here:

```
#info>i 
    {
        font-size:1.7em;
        color:#ccc;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
```

But only the `color` and `font-size` are working, the `margin`, `text-align` etc. don't work.
Does anybody understand what can be happening here?

**My jsfiddle showing the problem:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mibb/TLSSN/

**My Html:**

```
<div class="view second-effect">
      <img src="image1.jpg"  />
      <div class="mask">
      <a href="#" id="info"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>       
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
#info>i 
{
    font-size:1.7em;
    color:#ccc;
    margin:0 auto;
} 

.view a#info 
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}

.view 
{
    width: 155px;
    height: 160px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
    cursor: default;
    margin-right:20px; 
    border:3px solid #ccc;
    margin-top:4px; 
}

.view .mask, .view .content 
{
    width: 155px;
    height: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.second-effect .mask 
{
    opacity: 0;
    overflow:visible;
    border:0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.second-effect:hover .mask 
{
    opacity: 1;
    border:78px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

Comment: Is my icon font that Im formating here #info>i

Comment: In the html is this: <i class="fa fa-download"></i>

Comment: Yes but the "fa fa-download" is a code to show an image, that is a icon font! I´m using icon fonts from awesome font site. And we can format that icons as text, aligning at center, giving font-size, etc!

Comment: Right, but you aren't linking to the fontawesome css file at all.

Comment: In the jsfiddle I dont have because I dont know if its possible link the awesome font in jsfiddle but in my html code I have the link to the fontawesome sure!

Comment: please a sample image of how you want to stay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm pretty sure you're aligning your icon's 0,0 coordinate to the center instead of aligning the center of the icon to the center of the parent.

I made your fiddle work by adding this:

```
margin-top:-12px;
margin-bottom:-12px;

// This would work too
margin: -12px 0;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLSSN/22/)

Btw, you can add font awesome, or any other external file, to a JSFiddle through the External Resources tab on the left side.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt remeber to try with negative values. But I need to put that negative values that you say on my #info>i. In your example you have put in the .view a#info  but when I try to put the margin here nothing happens!